# check existance of relation across databases in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have blogs table in **base** connection that Blog model is like below

```
class Blog extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'base';
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Category', 'id', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

and I have categories table in **shop** connection

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'shop';
    public function blogs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Blog', 'category_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

now, I want to show list of categories with their blogs if there is any blog.

my query :

```
CategoryBlogResource::collection(
            Category::with('blogs')
                ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                ->get()
        );
```

as I searched, has() didn't work across databases
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

how can I handle existence of blogs for each category?
I don't want to show categories that doesn't have any blog.

Comment: I don't know why but i don't have a good feeling about your database design, why your blog and categories are in different connections?

Comment: Have you tried prefixing column names with their db names, like so `database.column` in your relationship definition?

Comment: @AbolfazlMohajeri because I want to use category table that exist in other program(shop)

Comment: @Nasa could you please explain more? I put my relations and model in quetion

Answer (score 0):

you should use has() instead of with()
why wont work on db? is it designed for...
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Comment: because tables aren't in the same database, has() didn't work, I mentioned in my question https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Answer (score 0):

I ever faced this problem too, just chaining **with()** and **has()** method

```
CategoryBlogResource::collection(
    Category::with('blogs')     // Get Relationship data
    ->has('blogs')              // check if category has any blog
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->get();
);
```

I assume your relationship function on your model is correct. If you want to filter for example "*grab any categories which blog title starts with 'abcde'*" then you should use [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method

Comment: because tables aren't in the same database, has() didn't work.

Comment: are these database is same type? MySQL + MySQL or Postgre + Postgre? try to use multiple connections. Maybe this will help you lil bit. https://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections